# SUPL MS-Assisted - what measurements are sent

Tags: gps, geolocation, location, supl-2.0

In the `MS-assisted` case, it is the `GPS` receiver which sends the `measurements` for the `SLP` to calculate and revert. I understand the `measurements` include the `Ephemeris`, `Iono`, `DGPS` etc + `Doppler shift` that are sent. Please let me know if my understanding is right.

Does the `SET` send the code (the entire data transmitted by satellites as is) that it `receives` as is or splits it into the above components and send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the assistance information in SUPL is encapsulated using RRLP protocol (Radio resource location services (LCS) protocol for GSM), RRC (Radio Resource Control for UMTS) or TIA 801 (for CDMA 2000) or LPP (LTE Positioning Protocol for LTE). I'm just looking at RRLP standard [ETSI TS 101 527](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101500_101599/101527/07.02.00_60/ts_101527v070200p.pdf). The following part sounds interesting:

> A.3.2.5 GPS Measurement Information Element
>
> The purpose of the GPS Measurement Information element is to provide
>   GPS measurement information from the MS to the SMLC. This information
>   includes the measurements of code phase and Doppler, which enables the
>   network-based GPS method where position is computed in the SMLC. The
>   proposed contents are shown in table A.5 below, and the individual
>   fields are described subsequently.

In subsequent section it is defined as:

- reference frame - optional, 16 bits - *the frame number of the last measured burst from the reference BTS modulo 42432*
- GPS TOW (time of week) - mandatory, 24 bits, unit of 1ms
- number of satellites - mandatory, 4 bits

Then for each satellite the following set of data is transmitted:

- satellite ID - 6 bits
- C/No - 6 bits
- Doppler shift - 16 bits, 0.2Hz unit
- Whole Chips - 10 bits
- Fractional Chips - 10 bits
- Multipath Indicator - 2 bits
- Pseudorange Multipath Error - 3+3 bits (mantissa/exponent)

I'm not familiar that much with GPS operation to understand all the parameters, but as far as I understand:

- C/No is simply a signal(carrier) to noise ratio
- Doppler shift - gives the frequency shift for a given satellite, obviously
- Whole/Fractional Chips together give the phase (and thus satellite distance)

My understanding is that things like almanac, ephemeris, Iono, DGPS are all known on the network side. As far as I know those things are transferred from network to MS in MS-based mode.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the precise info! So then, only the real time data that the receiver has to inevitably collect to get the dot position are sent. These are not including the ephemeris, almanac etc which are known on network side

Comment: It should be RRLP not RRLC

Answer (score 2):

Measurements collected from MS-assisted location requests include:

- Satellite ID
- code phase - whole chips
- code phase - fractional chips
- Doppler
- Signal strength
- Multipath indicator
- pseudorange RMS indicator

In addition, the GPS time of measurements is also provided as one value (in milliseconds) for the time which all measurements are valid.

In practice, the required fields that need to be accurate and correct are:

- Satellite ID
- code phase - whole chips
- code phase - fractional chips
- Doppler

The code phase values for each satellite are almost always used for the most accurate location calculation.  Doppler values can be used to estimate a rough location but aren't usually accurate enough to really contribute to the final solution.

The other values for signal strength, multipath indication, and RMS indicator usually vary in meaning so much between vendors that they don't really provide much benefit for the position calculation.  They would normally be used for things like weighting other values so that good satellites count more in the final position.

The network already knows (or should know) the ephemeris and ionospheric model.  They are not measurements collected by the handset.